# Gráfico de Barras separadas - python [colab]

Tags: python, data, ciência-de-dados, chart

Pessoal como faço para fazer com que no gráfico as barras de receitas e gastos fiquem separadas e não sobrepostas? Agradeço de puderem ajudar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#saldo em caixa no início do período
saldo_inicial = 20000

valores = {
    'meses': ['janeiro', 'fevereiro', 'março'],
    'receitas': [80000, 50000, 90000],
    'gastos': [60000, 70000, 65000],    
}

print(pd.DataFrame(valores))

#definindo o fluxo de caixa de cada período
fluxo_janeiro = saldo_inicial + valores['receitas'][0] - valores['gastos'][0]
fluxo_fevereiro = fluxo_janeiro + valores['receitas'][1] - valores['gastos'][1]
fluxo_marco = fluxo_fevereiro + valores['receitas'][2] - valores['gastos'][2]

print('\n')
print('>Série com o fluxo de caixa de janeiro à março:')
fluxo_de_caixa = [fluxo_janeiro, fluxo_fevereiro, fluxo_marco]

#criando um novo dicionáriouma para Series do fluxo de caixa
valores_series = {
    'meses': 'fluxo de caixa',
    'janeiro': fluxo_janeiro,
    'fevereiro': fluxo_fevereiro,
    'março': fluxo_marco,
}

#criando Series
df = pd.Series(valores_series);
print(df);

#criando gráficos
print('\n')
plt.rc('figure', figsize = (15, 8))
area = plt.figure()

g1 = plt.plot(valores['meses'], fluxo_de_caixa, label = 'Fluxo de Caixa', color = 'gray', marker='o')       #plotando fluxo de caixa
g2 = plt.bar(valores['meses'], valores['receitas'], label = 'Receitas', color = 'blue')   #plotando receitas
g3 = plt.bar(valores['meses'], valores['gastos'], label = 'Gastos', color = 'red')     #plotando gastos
plt.title('Fluxo de caixa')
plt.legend()

plt.plot()
```

Comment: Faça os gráficos com a biblioteca seaborn, acho q vai te ajudar. Ai caso precise configurar o gráfico use a matplot

Answer (score -2):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você tem que atribuir um dimensionamento as colunas,
eu refiz a parte do seu código para você usar como referência.Tem outros bons exemplos na biblioteca da matplotlib https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html

#Importando as Bibliotecas
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np#Importar essas libs adicionais

from pylab import rcParams

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 4 #Definindo o tamanho do gráfico

#saldo em caixa no início do período
saldo_inicial = 20000

valores = {
'meses': ['janeiro', 'fevereiro', 'março'],
'receitas': [80000, 50000, 90000],
'gastos': [60000, 70000, 65000],
}

print(pd.DataFrame(valores))

#definindo o fluxo de caixa de cada período
fluxo_janeiro = saldo_inicial + valores['receitas'][0] - valores['gastos'][0]
fluxo_fevereiro = fluxo_janeiro + valores['receitas'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FNG8.png) - valores['gastos'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FNG8.png)
fluxo_marco = fluxo_fevereiro + valores['receitas'][2] - valores['gastos'][2]

print('\n')
print('>Série com o fluxo de caixa de janeiro à março:')
fluxo_de_caixa = [fluxo_janeiro, fluxo_fevereiro, fluxo_marco]

#criando um novo dicionáriouma para Series do fluxo de caixa
valores_series = {
'meses': 'fluxo de caixa',
'janeiro': fluxo_janeiro,
'fevereiro': fluxo_fevereiro,
'março': fluxo_marco,
}

#criando Series
df = pd.Series(valores_series);
print(df);

## Atribuindo a um dataframe e gerando o gráfico- Parte nova do código

data=pd.DataFrame(valores)

labels = list(data['meses'])

receitas = list(round(data['receitas'],2))

gastos = list(round(data['gastos'],2))

x = np.arange(len(labels))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

rects1 = ax.bar(x , receitas, width=0.1, label='Receitas')

rects2 = ax.bar(x + 0.1, gastos, width=0.1, label='Gastos')

g1 = plt.plot(valores['meses'], fluxo_de_caixa, label = 'Fluxo de Caixa', color = 'gray', marker='o')

## Adicionando o nome das labels, titulo, etc.

ax.set_title('Fluxo de Caixa')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical')
ax.legend()

plt.show()

Comment: Obrigado, Vigo. Ajudou muito aqui.